# Check if polynomial can be rook polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, chessboard

How to verify if a given polynomial is a rook polynomial? Let’s assume I have a chessboard 5x5 and those 5 polynomials:

1. $r(x) = 2 + 11x + 35x^2 + 50x^3 + 26x^4 + 5x^5$
2. $r(x) = 1 + 15x + 35x^2 + 50x^3 + 26x^4 + 5x^6$
3. $r(x) = 1 + 10x + 35x^2 + 50x^3 + 26x^4 + 5x^5$
4. $r(x) = 1 + 15x + 35x^2 + 50x^3 + 5x^5$
5. $r(x) = 1 + 26x + 35x^2 + 50x^3 + 26x^4 +5x^5$

I know the first one can not be rook polynomial because there is 2 instead of 1 on the first position.

Second is not valid because six rooks can't be placed on 5x5 board($x^6$).

4th is also not valid because if 4 rooks can not be placed on the board then it's not possible to place 5 rooks(missing $x^4$).

I do not have a clue how to verify if 3rd and 5th are valid or not, any ideas?

Comment: Prepare a list of all rook polynomials up to degree 5. Check if the given polynomial is on that list.

Comment: To rule out the $5$th, look at the coefficient of $x^1$. Can there really be $26$ ways to place a single rook on a $5\times 5$ board?

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook_polynomial#Definition) the coefficient of $x^5$ is the number of ways to place 5 non-attacking rooks on a 5x5 board, and this is not $5$.

Every row and columm must have exactly one rook in such configurations, so you have 5 spots available for the first columm, 4 spots for the second and so on. So the $x^5$ coefficient must be $5!$. For this reason, none of these polynomials could be rook polynomials.

Comment: Similarly, the coefficient of $x^1$ should be $5^2 = 25$ because one rook can be placed in any square, and that rules out all five polynomials.